# Split string into phonemic segments

Tags: r, regex

I can't seem to figure out a seemingly simple task:

I have phonemic transcriptions of speech. To count the phonemes I want to split the strings into single phonemic segments. Unfortunately, the characters used for the phonemes are not 100% different from each other. For example, a long /i/ sound is transcribed `iː` (NB: `ː` is not a colon but a special char!) whereas a short /i/ sound may occasionally be transcribed `i`. This double use of the `i` in two distinct phonemes causes a problem in the split operation:

Test data:

```
test1 <- "dɪd ɛnɪbɒdi liːv ðeə glɑːsɪz hɪə lɑːst wiːk sʌmbədi dɪd"
```

A vector of all phonemes:

```
phonemes <- c("ɪə","eɪ","ʊə","ɔɪ","aɪ","eə","aʊ","əʊ",   # diphthongs
              "iː","uː","ɜː","ɔː","ɑː",                  # long vowels
              "ə","ɪ", "ɛ","ɒ","ʌ","æ","i","ʊ",          # short vowels
              "j","w",                                   # semi-vowels
              "r","l",                                   # approximants
              "n","m","ŋ",                               # nasals
              "f","v","θ","ð","s","z","ʃ","ʒ","h",       # fricatives
              "ʧ","ʤ",                                   # affricates
              "p","b","t","d","k","g")                   # plosives
```

The alternation pattern:

```
phonemes_pattern <- paste0("(", paste0(phonemes, collapse = "|"), ")")
```

The `split`ting operation:

```
str_split(gsub(" ", "", test1), paste0("(?<=", phonemes_pattern, ")"))
[[1]]
 [1] "d"  "ɪ"  "d"  "ɛ"  "n"  "ɪ"  "b"  "ɒ"  "d"  "i"  "l"  "i"  "ː"  "v"  "ð"  "eə" "g"  "l"  "ɑː" "s"  "ɪ"  "z"  "h"  "ɪ"  "ə"  "l"  "ɑː" "s"  "t" 
[30] "w"  "i"  "ː"  "k"  "s"  "ʌ"  "m"  "b"  "ə"  "d"  "i"  "d"  "ɪ"  "d"  ""
```

The result is correct **except** for the long /i/ sound where the two characters `i`and `ː` are also separated. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not extract the `phonemes` instead ?

```
phonemes_pattern <- paste0(phonemes, collapse = "|")
stringr::str_extract_all(test1, phonemes_pattern)[[1]]

#[1] "d"  "ɪ"  "d"  "ɛ"  "n"  "ɪ"  "b"  "ɒ"  "d"  "i"  "l" 
#[12] "iː" "v"  "ð"  "eə" "g"  "l"  "ɑː" "s"  "ɪ"  "z"  "h" 
#[23] "ɪə" "l"  "ɑː" "s"  "t"  "w"  "iː" "k"  "s"  "ʌ"  "m" 
#[34] "b"  "ə"  "d"  "i"  "d"  "ɪ"  "d"
```

Or in base R :

```
regmatches(test1, gregexpr(phonemes_pattern, test1))[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the `lookbehind` to a `lookahead` makes it work

```r
# using the unchanged phonemes vector
phonemes_pattern <- paste0(phonemes, collapse = "|")
str_split(gsub(" ", "", test1), paste0("(?=", phonemes_pattern, ")"))
```